# Protocol for asking for more information

Tags: discussion

Let's say I ask a question and I get a few suggestions. I try them out, they don't quite work, but due to the answers I have a newfound understanding of the problem, but it still isn't solved.

Is it appropriate to ask the same question again, obviously with the new information? Or should I just use edits on my original question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe edits are encouraged over duplicate questions.

If you did have two questions (or more depending on how many suggestions you get), at best you're splitting attention across a bunch of similar questions and at worst they're getting closed as duplicates and you're losing rep.  Remember that people will still be running into your original question, and they won't know that the answers already provided haven't worked.

Moreover, updating your question helps the people already answering as they will see the new information and might have more ideas.  It also shows that you are engaged in getting an answer rather than shooting off a bunch of questions and then vanishing quietly.

Also remember, by editing your question, you'll be bumping it back to the top of the question list, so even more people might see it.

Answer (score 8):

If your new understanding changes the *problem* then post a new question.

If your new understanding changes how you view the problem, edit the question to better represent the problem.

If your understanding doesn't change the problem, but changes how you view the answers, add comments to the answers asking for additional clarification.